# Numpy solution to avoid nested loops for tensor construction

Tags: python, numpy

I need to perform the following tensor operation:

```
T[i,j,k] = A[i,k]*B[j,k]
```

My brute force solution is:

```
T = np.zeros(shape=(N,N,N))
for i in range(N):
   for j in range(N):
      for k in range(N):
         T[i,j,k] = A[i,k] * B[j,k]
```

Is there a more optimal numpy approach to this? (Note: this is not a simple outer product.) I imagine it involves using np.tensordot with an appropriate axes value, but the documentation does not make it very clear how to use it.

This will also in the end need to work in general for any number of k dimensions:

```
T[i,j,k1,k2,k3,...] = A[i,k1,k2,k3,...]*B[j,k1,k2,k3,...]
```

Comment: Simply do - `A[:,None]*B` or `A[:,np.newaxis]*B`.

Comment: The `dot` in `tensordot` means that it applies `dot`, sum-of-products, to tensors.  So it's not a `tensor` constructor, at least not in the `outer product` sense.  While you can play some tricks with the `axes` parameter, it isn't nearly as useful as `matmul` (batched dot), `einsum`, or 'plain-old' `broadcasting`.

Comment: By the way, in `numpy` 'tensor' doesn't have a special meaning.  Its arrays are inherently multidimensional, where the number of dimensions can be 0, 1, 2 ... 31.  The names, 'vector', 'matrix', 'tensor' come from outside.  They may be useful when visualizing the arrays, but they aren't much help when searching the documentation.